# В чем разница между socket'ом и websocket'ом?

Tags: сокет, websocket

Я понял, что сокет это грубо говоря гнездо-интерфейс (в качестве параметров IP компьютера и порта), которое создает программа, через которое к ней может подключиться другой компьютер прописав тот же адрес и порт. И тут замаячили веб-сокеты. В чем между ними разница?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

веб сокет - это просто обертка вокруг обычных TCP сокетов (хотя я подозреваю, что теоретически может быть и вокруг чего угодно, что может выглядеть как сокет). Отличие от обычных сокетов в том, что протокол обмена стандартизирован (но существует несколько стандартов) и обмен сильно похож на обычный HTTP. Также браузеры умеют его из коробки (не все правда). А также вебсокеты помогают с безопасностью и прочими плюшками.

Зачем это нужно? да все просто. Люди в современном вебе хотят чатов, пуш нотификаций, а обычный http однонаправленный и приходиться постоянно стучаться на сервер. Обычные сокеты в JavaScript добавить сложно (о том почему - умолчим), поэтому сделали красивую обертку.

Comment: то есть веб-сокет,это тот же сокет, только более навороченный?

Comment: я бы сказал не так. Все, что можно сделать через вебсокет, можно сделать через обычный сокет, но не наоборот. Другое дело, что в некоторых случаях доступен только вебсокет (браузер, некоторые мобильные устройства).

Comment: значит веб соккеты создали,чтобы можно было с помощью браузера открывать дуплексный канал,используя tcp-протокол?

Comment: Это одна из причин.

Comment: В ответе полная каша.

Comment: Напишите лучше:)

Comment: @KoVadim Уже написал. Просто я понимаю, что описание Вами давалось как более "приземленное", так сказать для новичков. Но, когда идет подмена понятий, я не могу пройти мимо :) Сейчас уже мой ответ будет, скорее всего, не актуальным. Но может, в последствие, он кому-либо и пригодится (думаю, что даже Вам будет полезно прочитать :) ).

Answer (score 34):

**Socket** - это действительно **программный интерфейс**. Это абстрактное понятие, которое, в большинстве случаев, используется для коммуникации программ в сети (но не только).

**WebSocket** - это **протокол** (какой-либо заранее оговоренный порядок) обмена данными (как, например, http, ftp, ssl и т.д.). Этот протокол идет поверх (передается посредством) протокола TCP.

**Socket** и **WebSocket** - это **разные понятия** в принципе. При работе по протоколу WebSocket вы будете использовать обычные сокеты для соединения. Так же как и при работе с другими протоколами будут использованы сокеты (и для работы с http, с ftp и др.).

Например, рассмотрим строку вида - ws://127.0.0.1:15000. В ней ws - это именно указание на то, что при обмене данными будет использован протокол WebSocket. 127.0.0.1 - ip адрес компьютера, 15000 - порт, на который производится подключение. Так вот 127.0.0.1:15000 - эта пара, если можно так выразится, и является сокетом.

Протокол WebSocket создавался для того, чтобы можно было поддерживать длительные неразрывные соединения между браузером (который является клиентом) и веб-сайтом (который является сервером).

Протокол WebSocket не похож на HTTP. Единственное, чем он напоминает HTTP - только одним самым первым запросом на подключение (так называемым рукопожатием/handshake). Это было сделано, потому что изначально протокол рассчитан на работу в браузере и необходимо было определение возможности поддержки его. После того, как соединение установлено, ничего похожего на протокол HTTP в протоколе WebSocket даже близко нет.

Сам протокол WebSocket не гарантирует никакой безопасности для передаваемых данных. Минимальное кодирование, которое он предусматривает - это банальная ксорка (XOR). При этом маска для ксорки передается вместе с сообщением. И предназначена эта ксорка для передачи данных через прокси сервера, которые ничего не знают о протоколе WebSocket. Это не защита ваших данных - это защита прокси сервера. И в обратную сторону (от сайта к браузеру) данные не кодируются ксоркой, ввиду отсутствия необходимости.

Именно отсутствие каких-либо наворотов в протоколе WebSocket и дает ему возможность быстрой работы.

Comment: Согласно Вашему ответу, [wss](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#page-55) уже отменили:)

Comment: @KoVadim Согласно моему ответу, следует различать протоколы между собой. Речь в вопросе (и ответе) идет именно о websocket. Не следует думать, что протокол websocket обеспечивает безопасность. Упомянутый Вам wss - это не отдельный протокол - это протокол websocket "обернутый" в протокол TLS (наследник протокола SSL). Именно протокол TLS обеспечивает безопасность данных и он не имеет никакого отношения к протоколу Websocket. Как и в своем ответе выше Вы опять же стараетесь упростить/подменить понятия.

Comment: а я не говорил, что wss - это отдельный протокол. Я даже дал ссылку на rfc.

Да, Вы и сами хорошо подменяете вещи. Безопасность данных это не только наличие шифрования.

Comment: @KoVadim :O Я вообще не поднимал ни в вопросе ни в комментариях понятия шифрования, тем более в контексте безопасности. Видимо, Вы запутались в своих же ответах/комментариях, потому что именно Вы писали `вебсокеты помогают с безопасностью`. Я же четко в ответе указал, что то кодирование (заметьте, не шифрование), которое предусмотрено в протоколе websocket, не имеет никакого отношения к безопасности.

Comment: "помогают" - это значит есть готовые средства, которые уже опробованы.  То же шифрование, тот же wss и другое. Но слово "помогают" не значит, что оно глубоко включено в протокол (тогда я бы употребил бы "является составляющей частью").

Я не запутался, да, тот ответ писался именно так, что бы его понял вопрошающий и он не  был рассчитан на более подготовленного читателя. Подготовленным читателям мой ответ не нужен.

Comment: @KoVadim Я прекрасно понимаю, что Ваш ответ для неподготовленного читателя. Именно это я и отразил в комментарии под Вашим ответом. И именно потому, что в Вашем ответе `смешались в кучу кони, люди`, я и счёл нужным дать свой ответ.

Comment: классный ответ.все разложили по полочкам. такой вопрос:вебсоккетное соединение и http-соединение-это разные вещи друг с другом не связанные, или же вебсоккетное соединение создается на базе http соединения?

Comment: @Iga Соединение по протоколу WebSocket и соединение по протоколу HTTP - разные вещи (разные соединения). При соединении по протоколу HTTP задействован, как правило, 80-й порт в качестве второго параметра сокета. Для Websocket - тот порт, который Вы укажете. И в одном и в другом случае передача данных идет поверх протокола TCP. Нет, не создается соединение WebSocket на базе HTTP соединения. Соединение WebSocket создается браузером и при этом идет рукопожатие в виде HTTP заголовка. Из-за этого и возникает путаница (ощущение), что есть зависимость протокола WebSocket от HTTP.

Comment: @Iga Но необходимо понимать, что WebSocket отдельный протокол. И его реализация может быть "за пределами" браузера и веб-сервера. Вы можете писать свой сервер и свой клиент, которые будут работать по протоколу WebSocket. И в общем-то вся работа с протоколом WebSocket выглядит чем-то похожим на работу с обычным TCP протоколом.

Comment: чем "протокол TCP" отличается от понятия "Socket", ведь по сути это одно и тоже. Для чего ввели понятие Socket, ведь можно было говорить просто TCP, и тогда бы соединение с веб-сервером осуществлялось не по WebSocket, а называлось WebTCP или что то в этом духе