# Web Socket vs Network Socket

Tags: java, сокет, websocket

Объясните пожалуйста в чем разница между Web socket и Network socket? Как они работают?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [В чем разница между socket'ом и websocket'ом?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/507746/%d0%92-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-socket%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b8-websocket%d0%be%d0%bc)

Comment: Попробовать поискать уже не получается?