# В каких прикладных задачах применяются сокеты C#?

Tags: c#, сокет, сетевое-программирование

Как инструмент мне понятно, [что такое сокет](https://professorweb.ru/my/csharp/web/level3/3_1.php):

> Когда двум процессам, находящимся на разных хостах, необходимо обмениваться информацией по сети, будь то локальная сеть или Интернет, им необходимо открыть сокет для установления связи, а также для обмена любыми потоками данных. ([itigic](https://itigic.com/ru/tcp-and-udp-socket-what-they-are-for-and-differences-with-ports/))

> Можно представить, что сокет — это виртуальная труба, которую строят между двумя приложениями, чтобы гонять между ними данные. Приложения видят только концы трубы, а как проходит трубопровод — они не знают и им неважно. ([thecode](https://thecode.media/socket/))

Всё началось с того, что я читал статьи на metanit [по сетевому программированию на С#](https://metanit.com/sharp/net/). В ней достаточно подробно описывается работа с сокетами, оберткой в виде tcp, udp. Но перед этим я работал с библиотекой System.Net.Http, c помощью которой успешно общался с сервером - отсюда и родилось непонимание, зачем все эти сокеты.

Меня интересует вопрос, стоит ли использовать сокеты в 2022 году, если я, к примеру, делаю небольшое веб-приложение на asp.net core, в котором я передаю и получаю данные? Или можно обойтись библиотеками System.Net.Http, System.Net.WebSockets  [[ответ на вопрос]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/507746/341669). Являются ли эти библиотеки высокоуровневыми аналогами?

Хотелось бы узнать о практическом применении сокетов, в каких кейсах без них не обойтись?

Вопрос на английском SO, про [способы передачи данных между процессами](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16460620/13326324).

Comment: Сокеты используют при сдаче лабораторных работ по сокетам. А так, как вы совершенно правильно заметили, существуют другие, более высокоуровневые и удобные средства для работы с сетью.

Comment: Сокеты это низкоуровневая концепция, и все эти библиотеки (Net.Http, WebSockets и т.д.) используют сокеты, реализуя поверх некий протокол (http, web sockets). Бывает так, что вам нужно общаться по сети с программой которая использует нестандартный протокол, или вы решили "для производительности" сами реализовать нестандартный протокол. Тогда придется использовать сокеты напрямую, потому что готовых библиотек реализующих данный протокол не будет.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте высокоуровневые библиотеки, так быстрее и безопаснее, они внутри скорее всего используют сокеты. Для вашего образования знать как это устроено - полезно. Для разработки приложения это вам не пригодится. Тут уже вопрос приоритетов.

Использовать их можно где угодно, где нужно межпроцессное(даже по сети) взаимодействие

Answer (score 0):

Единственный раз, когда мене приходилось использовать сокеты - это когда я полключался к серверу, который поддерживает только UDP сокеты.

Также есть такое понятие, как веб-сокеты, которые позволяют серверу отправлять сообщение клиентам, но над этим уже много абстракций и прямо байты никто руками не высылает.

Если вы пишете обычный веб сервер, где все запросы инициирует клиент, то про сокеты можно не париться.